# abstraction and encapsulation in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

when we write all our application  methods and variables in a classes is nothing but data abstraction and encapsulation. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be true but depends over your design. An Application is nothing but combination of classes working as units to accomplish task. So every thing is something from a class like method, property etc,  in Object Oriented Methodology

**Abstraction:**

By this feature of object oriented programming it is possible to represent the needed information in program without presenting the details.

**Data Encapsulation:**

Data Encapsulation is the process of combining data and functions into a single unit called class. By this method one cannot access the data directly. Data is accessible only through the functions present inside the class. Thus Data Encapsulation gave rise to the important concept of data hiding.

reference: [**what is data abstraction and data encapsulation**](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/105237-what-data-abstraction-data-encapsulation.aspx)

Comment: Mr. Asad Butt in greekinterview i saw like this 
Abstraction: Hides the implementation details of your methods. Provides a base to variations in the application which can grow over a period of time.

Encapsulation: Hides the private data elements of the class and exposes only the required things to the clients.

Answer (score 0):

It's [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), but not necessarily [Abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_abstraction#Abstraction_in_object_oriented_programming).

In OO, abstraction *typically* refers to type abstraction.  So, it can be argued that using a class type at all is abstraction, but many would say no you'd have to be using polymorphism or inheritance in some way.